# stop while loop when the text ends

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I have a program that loops through the lines of a book to match some tags I've created indicating the start and the end of each chapter of this book. I want to separate each chapter into a different file. The program finds each chapter and asks the user to name the file, then it continues until the next chapter and so on. I don't know exactly where to put my "break" or something that could stop my loop. The program runs well but when it reaches the last chapter it goes back to the first chapter. I want to stop the loop and terminate the program when the tags and the chapters finish and also print something like "End of chapters". Can anyone help me with that? The code is below:

```
import re
def separate_files ():
    with open('sample.txt') as file:
        chapters = file.readlines()



pat=re.compile(r"[@introS\].[\@introEnd@]")
reg= list(filter(pat.match, chapters))
txt=' '

while True:
    for i in chapters:
        if i in reg:
            print(i)
            inp=input("write text a file? Y|N: ")
            if inp =='Y':
                txt=i
                file_name=input('Name your file: ')
                out_file=open(file_name,'w')
                out_file.write(txt)
                out_file.close()
                print('text', inp, 'written to a file')
            elif inp =='N':
                break
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue


separate_files()
```

Comment: "but when it reaches the last chapter it goes back to the first chapter"... Yes. Because the `for i in chapters:` loop ends and the external while repeats everything. Just remove the while (and while you're at it, also the `else: continue` at the end, which I'm 200% sure it's wrongly put there)

Comment: Using "While True" will never end unless you break it yourself, I would recommend finding an actual true/false conditional check to use with your while statement so the looping ends when that condition is false. Or you could just remove the while since you are already looping over the data with your "for i in chapters" statement.

Comment: Is the `while` loop supposed to be inside `separate_files`? (Seems so, since otherwise `chapters` isn't defined.)

Comment: @GPhilo, ok! I will try to remove the while True.

Comment: That's not the only error you have in the code, but you can start from there. As chepner pointed out, `chapters` is not defined anywhere

Comment: Do you just want to write the chapter names to different files or the entire chapter content? What does your sample.txt contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a simpler definition would be

```
import re
def separate_files ():
    pat = re.compile(r"[@introS\].[\@introEnd@]")

    with open('sample.txt') as file:

        for i in filter(pat.match, file):
            print(i)
            inp = input("write text to a file? Y|N: ")
            if inp != "Y":
                continue

            file_name = input("Name of your file: ")
            with open(file_name, "w") as out_file:
                out_file.write(i)
            print("text {} written to a file".format(i))
```

Continue the loop as soon as possible in each case, so that the following code doesn't need to be nested more and more deeply. Also, there's no apparent need to read the entire file into memory at once; just match each line against the pattern as it comes up.

You might also consider simply asking for a file name, treating a blank file name as declining to write the line to a file.

```
for i in filter(pat.match, file):
    print(i)
    file_name = input("Enter a file name to write to (or leave blank to continue: ")
    if not file_name:
        continue

    with open(file_name, "w") as out_file:
        out_file.write(i)
    print("text {} written to {}".format(i, file_name)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering if it is possible to ask the program  create the files and give a name to each file automatically instead of asking the user to name a file to created it. Is that possible? If so, could you please show me how do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't run your code but I assume if you remove the

```
while True:
```

line it should work fine. This will always be executed as there is nothing checked